# Logrotate for log files without `.log` extension

Tags: linux, redhat, logrotate

I need to have `logrotate` rotate all the logs in a direcory, but those log files have NO extension.
I'd like to know if the Linux `logrotate` command also works for files not having `.log` extension.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course this will work. Use a config like this:

```
/path/to/YOURLOGFILE {
    monthly
    rotate 12
    compress
    ... more settings
}
```

into `/etc/logrotate.d/your-service`. Even the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) provides an example, it shows how to rotate `/var/log/messages`